# OneNote 2013 corrupts SharePoint 2010 document sets

Tags: document-set

all.  I have a few SharePoint 2010 libraries configured to use document sets.  The document set content type is configured to provide an Open Notebook.onetoc2 by default.  OneNote 2010 uses the document set as the notebook container folder, allowing all of the notebook's contents to be stored in the document set.  It works great.

However, we're now experiencing a problem with this method since several users have upgraded to OneNote 2013.  If a user with contribute permissions opens a notebook stored in a document set with OneNote 2013, the document set's icon changes to that of a OneNote folder.  The document set's properties still report it to be a document set, but it no longer behaves as one.  Clicking it either tries to open the notebook (if Office web apps are enabled) or takes the user into the document set as if it were a normal folder.

I don't know if this is a bug or behavior by design.  Either way, I haven't been able to find any information on it.  Any advice would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: is the item's content type still "document set" or did it get changed to some special OneNote content type?  If so, can you change it back?

Comment: The content type is still "Document Set".  I've changed it to "Folder" and back again, but it doesn't help.  Regardless of the content type that SharePoint reports, it continues to look and act like a OneNote folder.

Comment: What does Microsoft say about the compatibility of OneNote 2013 and SharePoint 2010?

Answer (score 1):

We ended up pulling a Microsoft support ticket to solve this problem.  They acknowledged that is a bug, though it will take them some time to release a patch that will fix it.

The workaround is to include a .txt file in each document set, which will prevent it from being corrupted by OneNote 2013.  Adding one after the fact, however, does not cause it to revert back.  Our solution is to add an empty .txt file to the custom document set content type we're using, so that it's provisioned automatically when new document sets are created.